# Safe number of rows to select from in a single query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, scalability

this is not actually a programming questions tho. I was just wondering what the safe number of rows to select in a single query from a database is.

Currently, in our (company's) app, its coded to select 300 rows and then split it into pages. It scales(speed and performance) well on the server, however, the number of additions to the database is really growing fast; actually per day.

So in a situation that we have over 5,000 customer feedback filed per week, i want to know the safe limit i could increase the `select query` to. also without affecting speed/performance  for the non-IT staff..

Thanks.

Comment: I guess this will depend in your Hardware infrastructure. The more hardware and connectivity capabilities you have the higher the number of rows you can retrieve

Comment: There is NO way to answer this. 3000 rows in a database is essentially **NOTHING**. what's your client environment? Is your server ram constricted? What DB are you using? blah blah blah blah blah

Comment: how long is a piece of string?

Comment: @MarcB the server is on a VPS, the DB is MySQL, RAM is 2.5Gig dev environment is PHP5

Comment: only you can answer this by testing on your hardware with your software.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple answer to this question, the amount of rows which are safe to fetch differ between how the queries are optimized, your table is optimized, and how much memory / CPU the computer / server has at each time.

If your table is properly indexed (if you don't know what it means then you should read about it to make sure you're not going to kill your queries) then in general the amount of rows selected doesn't matter.

Also make sure you're not doing SELECT `*` when you select your rows, SQL server spends lots of time resolving this, instead properly name the columns you need.

Basic answer is: If you really need all the rows then there is no safe number of rows, you can fetch them all, just make sure you've optimized the SELECT query and the table structure like mentioned. If you can limit the rows then do so. The difference should not be more than 0.5 - few seconds and if the system is indeed that large then it's simply something you have to live with. Usually you can get away with showing only a small subset of rows but allow the user to ask for more, or even better, allow them to determine for how long they're willing to wait by allowing him to determine the number of rows fetched (if what you're trying to achieve allows).

The amount of rows you're talking about is, though, not considered such big of a deal, but bad design can cause it to become big of a deal.

Comment: thanks @jonast...really appreciate your input...will look in to these..thanks

Comment: @VyrenMedia You're welcome, you can wait for some time to see if you can get better answers but I've made my point :)

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of safe should consider the following :-

- **Performance**
  As others indicated, that can vary, and 5000 is not a really large number. You will have to time your processing and determine what is acceptable.

  **- Resource to handle the data**
  PHP is susceptible to memory exhausted errors since memory limits are normally set for PHP scripts, Again this will vary. If you are looping through and 'ignoring' a large number of rows, you might get away; if you are storing the data for later use, then you might run into memory issues. Again, fetching two number columns from 1 million rows will give different results that 1 million rows of 10 string fields.

  **- User Interactions**
  If your user is willing to sit and watch a million rows being processed then give them exactly that. For example, I wrote a migration script that processed some 300 000 rows, and the Client was ok with running the script. However, on the operation page, I am paging 30 rows at a time, because anything larger than that becomes too inconvenient to work with